# linux write(): does it try to write as many bytes as possible?

Tags: linux, network-programming

If I use `write` in this way: `write (fd, buf, 10000000 /* 10MB */)` where `fd` is a socket and uses blocking I/O, will the kernel tries to flush as many bytes as possible so that only one call is enough? Or I have to call `write` several times according to its return value? If that happens, does it mean something is wrong with `fd`?

============================== EDITED ================================

Thanks for all the answers. Furthermore, if I put `fd` into `poll` and it returns successfully with `POLLOUT`, so call to `write` cannot be blocked and writes all the data unless something is wrong with `fd`?

Comment: `10000000 /* 10MB */` - no, it's actually 9.54 MB

Comment: write() can return anything it wants (between -1 and N, both inclusive, with N being the third argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In blocking mode, [write(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) will only return if specified number of bytes are written. If it can not write it'll wait.

In non-blocking (`O_NONBLOCK`) mode it'll not wait. It'll return right then. If it can write all of them it'll be a success other wise it'll set errno accordingly. Then you have check the `errno` if its `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN` you have to invoke same `write` agian.

From manual of [`write(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write)

> The  number  of  bytes  written may be less than count if, for example, there is insufficient space on the underlying physical medium, or the RLIMIT_FSIZE resource
>          limit is encountered (see setrlimit(2)), or the call was interrupted by a signal handler after having written less than count bytes.  (See also pipe(7).)

So yes, there can be something wrong with `fd`.

Also note this

> A  successful return from write() does not make any guarantee that data has been committed to disk.  In fact, on some buggy implementations, it does not even guar‐
>          antee that space has successfully been reserved for the data.  The only way to be sure is to call fsync(2) after you are done writing all your data.

Comment: @Duck Are you talking about space limit and fsync issue?

Comment: Write will ONLY return with incomplete data beig sent if there is an error, or a signal is sent to the process, in which case `errno == EINTR`. The latter is pretty rare unless you use timers or some such in the code. But bear in mind that an `fd` may well be 'correct' at the start of the call, but if the other end closes the socket, your `fd` is no longer connected, so you'll get an incomplete write and `EPIPE` or some such ass the error.

Comment: This answer isn't correct.  Nonblocking only means that write() will block until something is written or an error occurs.  OP needs to code for incomplete writes.

Comment: @fizzer In practice all implementations block until all the data has been buffered, if not sent. There was a long thread about this on news:comp.protocols.tcp-ip a year or two ago, where all the implementors live.

Comment: Interesting.  I tried on Linux, and you appear to be correct (exception: I saw a partial write when sender got a signal).  I couldn't find this thread on google groups.  If you find it again, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/sysctl.conf is used in Linux to set parameters for the TCP protocol, which is what I assume you mean by a socket. There may be a lot of parameters there, but when you dig through it, basically there is a limit to the amount of data the TCP buffers can hold at one time.

So if you tried to write 10 MB of data at one go, write would return a `ssize_t` value equal to that value.  Always check the return value of the write() system call.  If the system allowed 10MB then write would return that value.

The value is

```
net.core.wmem_max = [some number]
```

If you change some number to a value large enough to allow 10MB you can write that much.  DON'T do that!  You could cause other problems.  Research settings before you do anything.  Changing settings can decrease performance.  Be careful.

```
http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp
```

has basic C information for TCP settings.  Also check out `/proc/sys/net` on your box.

One other point - TCP is a two way door, so just because you can send a zillion bytes at one time does not mean the other side can read it or even handle it. You socket may just block for a while.  And possibly your write() return value may be less than you hoped for.